# Chain rule in $\mathbb{R}^d$, with $d\ge 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces, chain-rule

Given $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open bounded set with Lipschitz boundary, let $v\in (H^1(\Omega))^d$, $\psi\in H^1(\Omega)$ $T_K(x):=B_K x+b_K$, where $B_K$ is a non-singular invertible matrix.

What I need to compute is

- $\nabla (\psi\circ T_K)$
- $D^\alpha(v\circ T_K)$, where $|\alpha|=m$ ($\alpha$ is a multiindex)

Could you give me some help? At least some hints.

Thank you very much!

Comment: A hint that you may have already tried: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: @toliveira Is this your hint?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I don't see why it doesn't apply to your case. Is it because of the definition of $v$ and $\psi$?